# Azure event hub: outgoing messages count is higher than incoming messages

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

Can someone please help me understand this?

Why do I see the outgoing messages count is higher than incoming messages count in azure event hub.?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please add more details like number of eventhubs, number of consumer groups, what SDK used to consume etc?

Answer (score 0):

Without a bit more context, it's difficult to do more than generalize.   I'm assuming that you're referring to the charts within the Azure portal.  If so, I would speculate that you may have more consumers reading the event stream than you do publishers sending events.

If you're willing to provide a bit more information about what metrics you're referring to and details about your publishing/consuming scenarios, we may be able to offer more insight.